# Javafx Image Crop according to hovering mouse position

Tags: java, javafx, hover, zooming, crop

I am developing a tracing program by placing dots to anatomical points on Xray. My problem is, I'm trying to zoom into my X-ray image (`Imageview`) while my mouse hovering onto it and displaying in another `Imageview`. I want my mouse to create a virtual rectangle around it and stays at the center while moving and transfers that live image to other small `Imageview`, I've done this so far but there are some glitches. My rectangle does not follow my mouse exactly as it should, and the glitch accelerates when I move into corners, What can you suggest? I'm sharing my error and my codes to clarify all those things.

Maybe I should create a rectangle shape and place it around mouse position and crop the image live, fit into the `zoomedImageview`, and display all the time, but I am stuck in this.

The main problem is, mouse position and center of `zoomedImageview`'s center position has to coincide all the time.

[image]

Xray Imageview Fitwidth-height is 800x800
zoomedImageview  Fitwidth-height is 250x250

```
public class DrawingController {

        @FXML 
    ImageView xrayImage;
        
         @FXML
    ImageView zoomedImage;

   public void initialize()
    {

   xrayImage.setOnMouseMoved(e -> {    //HOVERING ON XRAY
   
PixelReader reader = XrayImageview.getImage().getPixelReader();   
WritableImage newImage = new WritableImage(reader,

(int) e.getX(),  //x and y is picked according to hovering mouse position
   (int) e.getY(),
   (int) 250,     // 250x250 rectangle is requested.
   (int) 250);

zoomedImage.setImage(newImage);  // Displaying zoomed image

        });
}}
```

And My FXML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="913.0" prefWidth="1238.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="main.java.controllers.DrawingController">
   <children>
      <ImageView fitHeight="800.0" fitWidth="800.0" layoutX="418.0" layoutY="33.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" fx:id="xrayImage">
         <image>
            <Image url="@threatCare.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <ImageView fx:id="zoomedImage" fitHeight="250.0" fitWidth="250.0" layoutX="108.0" layoutY="433.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

And the Main class :

```
package main.java;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import main.java.database.DatabaseCreator;

import javax.swing.text.html.ImageView;
import java.awt.*;

public class Runner extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
     
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../resources/DrawingPanel.fxml"));

        primaryStage.setTitle("TreatCare Software Systems");
         Scene scene = new Scene(root,1200,950);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setMinWidth(1200);
        primaryStage.setMinHeight(950);
        primaryStage.setMaximized(true);
        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest( e -> SystemClose());
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void SystemClose(){
        System.exit(0);         
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: İ Just want to zoom into my imagewiew according to my hovering mouse position.Code is quite clear to understand I think,İ dont know what exactly are you looking for sorry for my ignorance @kleopatra

Comment: @kleopatra  I just edited my sharings, I'd be totally grateful if you can help me, This Algorithm has some glitches and I don't know why, I am sorry for my expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are scaling your image, so you need to convert your mouse coordinates according to that scaling.

From your .fxml file:

```
<ImageView fitHeight="800.0" fitWidth="800.0" layoutX="418.0" layoutY="33.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" fx:id="xrayImage">
```

There are three attributes in that line which scale the image:

- `fitWidth="800.0"` - scales image to 800 pixels wide
- `fitHeight="800.0"` - scales image to 800 pixels high
- `preserveRatio="true"` - overrides all scaling so image always has the same scale in both dimensions

So you need to multiply your mouse coordinates according to those:

```
xrayImage.setOnMouseMoved(e -> {    //HOVERING ON XRAY
    Image image = xrayImage.getImage();

    double x = e.getX();
    double y = e.getY();
    double xScale = (xrayImage.getFitWidth() > 0 ?
        image.getWidth() / xrayImage.getFitWidth() : 1);
    double yScale = (xrayImage.getFitHeight() > 0 ?
        image.getHeight() / xrayImage.getFitHeight() : 1);
    if (xrayImage.isPreserveRatio()) {
        double scale = Math.max(xScale, yScale);
        x *= scale;
        y *= scale;
    } else {
        x *= xScale;
        y *= yScale;
    }

    x = Math.max(0, x - 125);
    y = Math.max(0, y - 125);
    double width = Math.min(image.getWidth() - x, 250);
    double height = Math.min(image.getHeight() - y, 250);

    PixelReader reader = image.getPixelReader();   
    WritableImage newImage = new WritableImage(reader,
        (int) x, (int) y, (int) width, (int) height);

    zoomedImage.setImage(newImage);  // Displaying zoomed image
});
```

Comment: I don't know how to express my joy, İt is what I was looking for man thanks. But What if I want to increase the zoom amount??  @VGR

Comment: @Özden Since zoomedImage also defines fitWidth and fitHeight values, I imagine you can just change the 250 and 125 constants to something smaller to zoom in more.

Comment: @VGR  I changed all numeric values but it only results in discrepancy while hovering instead of zooming :(  ??

Comment: @Özden I changed 250 to 150 and I changed 125 to 75, and it worked fine for me.

Comment: @VGR, oh, I got it now, I didn't change proportionally, Everything is fine now, Thanks for all your support.

Answer (score 1):

I added a Pane to `DrawingPanel.fxml`. The purpose of the `Pane` is to show the borders of the cropped area (a marker):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="913.0" prefWidth="1238.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
                                                                            fx:controller="DrawingController">
   <children>
      <StackPane layoutX="418.0" layoutY="33.0">
         <children>
            <ImageView  fitHeight="800.0" fitWidth="800.0" preserveRatio="true" pickOnBounds="true" fx:id="xrayImagePane">
               <image>         
                <Image url="https://www.almanac.com/sites/default/files/image_nodes/cosmos-flower.jpg" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
            <!-- Stack a Pane over the ImageView. Add the marker to this Pane -->
            <Pane fx:id="markerPane" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
         </children>
      </StackPane>
      <ImageView fx:id="croppedImageView" fitHeight="250.0" fitWidth="250.0" layoutX="108.0" layoutY="433.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

The controller adds and updates the marker and updates the cropped image. I borrowed some code from [VGR's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69273511/3992939) for handling the scale, but note the use of `getLayoutBounds()` to calculate the scale:

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.scene.image.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

public class DrawingController {

    @FXML
    ImageView xrayImagePane;
    private Image fullImage;
    private PixelReader reader;

    @FXML
    Pane markerPane;
    private Rectangle marker;

    @FXML
    ImageView croppedImageView;

    private static int ZOOM_WONDOW_SIZE = 250;
    private static Color MARKER_COLOR  = Color.BLUE;

    @FXML
    public void initialize(){

        marker = new Rectangle(0,0, ZOOM_WONDOW_SIZE, ZOOM_WONDOW_SIZE);
        marker.setStroke(MARKER_COLOR);
        marker.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        marker.setStrokeWidth(3);
        markerPane.getChildren().add(marker);

        fullImage = xrayImagePane.getImage();
        reader = fullImage.getPixelReader();

        markerPane.setOnMouseMoved(e -> {
            updateMarker(e.getX(), e.getY());
            updateZoomImage();
        });
    }

    //update marker location based on mouse location
    private void updateMarker(double x, double y) {
        //use layout bounds because you do not know if the actual size is xrayImagePane.getFitWidth()
        //or fullImage.getWidth()
        Bounds imageViewBounds = xrayImagePane.getLayoutBounds();
        double imageWidth = imageViewBounds.getWidth();
        double newX= Math.max(0, x - ZOOM_WONDOW_SIZE/2 );
        newX =  newX + ZOOM_WONDOW_SIZE >= imageWidth ?  imageWidth - ZOOM_WONDOW_SIZE : newX;

        double imageHeight = imageViewBounds.getHeight();
        double newY = Math.max(0, y - ZOOM_WONDOW_SIZE/2 );
        newY=  newY + ZOOM_WONDOW_SIZE >= imageHeight ?  imageHeight - ZOOM_WONDOW_SIZE : newY;

        marker.setX(newX);
        marker.setY(newY);
    }

    //update zoomed image based on marker and scale
    private void updateZoomImage() {

        //adapted from VGR's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69273511/3992939
        double x = marker.getX();
        double y = marker.getY();
        double width = marker.getWidth();
        double height= marker.getHeight();
        //use layout bounds because you do not know if the actual size is xrayImagePane.getFitWidth()
        //or fullImage.getWidth()
        Bounds imageViewBounds = xrayImagePane.getLayoutBounds();

        double xScale = xrayImagePane.getFitWidth() > 0 ?
                            fullImage.getWidth() / imageViewBounds.getWidth() : 1;
        double yScale = xrayImagePane.getFitHeight() > 0 ?
                           fullImage.getHeight() / imageViewBounds.getHeight(): 1;
        if (xrayImagePane.isPreserveRatio()) {
            double scale = Math.min(xScale, yScale);
            x *= scale;
            y *= scale;
            width *= scale;
            height *= scale;
        } else {
            x *= xScale;
            y *= yScale;
            width *= xScale;
            height *= yScale;
        }

        WritableImage croppedImage = new WritableImage(reader,
                (int) x,
                (int) y,
                (int) width,
                (int) height
                );
        croppedImageView.setImage(croppedImage); 
    }
}
```

Test it using

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Runner extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("DrawingPanel.fxml"));

        primaryStage.setTitle("TreatCare Software Systems");
         Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest( e -> SystemClose());
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void SystemClose(){
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

---

[image]